# Does the Ring of Animal Friendship allow a save?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

The description for the [Ring of Animal Friendship](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-animal-friendship) says that it "affects an animal as if the wearer had cast *[charm animal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-animal)*".  However, no save is listed, and there is no clarification given to whether or not a save is allowed.  There are other items with similar effects that call out a save specifically, like the [Harp of Charming](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/harp-of-charming), for instance, so I'm not sure what the case would be here.

If the Ring of Animal Friendship allows a save, then what would the DC be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, all items implicitly allow saves for effects that mimic spells with saves.

> Aura faint enchantment; **CL 3rd**
>
> Slot ring; Price 10,800 gp; Weight —
>
> Description
>
> A ring of animal friendship always bears some sort of animal-like design in its craftsmanship. On command, this ring affects an animal as if the wearer had cast **charm animal**, causing the animal to regard the wearer as a trusted friend.

In [Saving Throws Against Magic Item Powers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Saving-Throws-Against-Magic-Item-Po), we see that:

> Magic items produce spells or spell-like effects. For a saving throw against a spell or spell-like effect from a magic item, **the DC is 10 + the level of the spell or effect + the ability modifier of the minimum ability score needed** to cast that level of spell.
>
> Staves are an exception to the rule. Treat the saving throw as if the wielder cast the spell, including caster level and all modifiers to save DCs.

In the case of this ring, is casting a level 1 spell, at caster level 3. This gives you all the information you need to calculate spell save DC (10 + 1 + 0 Wis bonus from Wis 11 = 11) and SR checks and dispel DCs and the like.

Comment: Yeesh.  That's a really crappy way to spend 10K, then.

Comment: It's at-will. So there's little preventing you from having an army of animal buddies except patience.

Comment: 1 hour/level duration makes the army management a bit tedious, and you still need to communicate. As a separate thought: not all items allow saves, items duplicating no-save spells don't.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ring of Animal Friendship allows a DC 11 will save.

From [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-animal) description of *charm animal* spell:

> This spell functions like charm person, except that it affects a creature of the animal type.

As we [know](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person), *charm person* allows a will save. 
Save DC, as correctly calculated by @mxyzlpk, is [10 + spell level + ability modifier of minimum required ability score](http://paizo.com/prd/magicItems.html#saving-throws-against-magic-item-powers) = 11.

Answer (score 1):

The save DC of the [*ring of animal friendship*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-animal-friendship)'s [*charm animal*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-animal) effect is 11.

That's because of this [rule](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Saving-Throws-Against-Magic-Item-Powers):

> Magic items produce spells or spell-like effects. For a saving throw against a spell or spell-like effect from a magic item, the DC is 10 + the level of the spell or effect + the ability modifier of the minimum ability score needed to cast that level of spell.

Casting the spell charm animal, a level 1 spell, requires an ability score of 11 because of this [rule](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Wisdom-Wis-):

> The minimum Wisdom score needed to cast a cleric, druid, or ranger spell is 10 + the spell's level.

The *ring*'s typically created with a caster level of 3 so that's used to determine the spell's effects. For example, the spell, if successful, has a duration of 3 hours because the duration of the spell *charm animal* is based on the duration of the spell [*charm person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person).

Because of the hoops one must jump through to determine a magic item's saving throw DC, most items list that information instead.